# How can I update a PySimpleGUI window while my code runs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, pysimplegui

I have a process which I need to put a GUI in front of. As the code runs, I want to update the window to let the user know the progress and any errors.

The 2 things I'm trying to achieve are:

1. Update the window as the code runs.
2. Use a function to do this (where is this best positioned?).

My code so far.

```
from time import sleep


import PySimpleGUI as sg
log_entries=""

sg.theme('BluePurple')

layout = [[sg.Text('LOG:')],
          [sg.Text(log_entries, key='-logtext-')],
          [sg.Button('Start'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

log_window = sg.Window('Pattern 2B', layout, finalize=True)

while True:  # Event Loop
    event, values = log_window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit' or event == None:
        break
    elif event == 'Start':

        def add_to_log(window, text, log_entries, text_colour='black'):
            log_entries = log_entries + "\n" + text
            window[-'logtext-'].update(log_entries, text_color=text_colour)
            return

        # Update the "output" text element to be the value of "input" element
        log_window['-logtext-'].update(log_entries)

        add_to_log(log_window, "Found file", log_entries)
        sleep(0.25) # sleep simulates the time it takes for the code to run
        add_to_log(log_window, "Load into pandas", log_entries)
        sleep(0.25)
        add_to_log(log_window, "Error", log_entries, text_colour='red')
        sleep(0.25)
        add_to_log(log_window, "Assign voucher codes", log_entries)
        sleep(0.25)
        add_to_log(log_window, "Splt into outputs", log_entries)
        sleep(0.25)
        add_to_log(log_window, "Saving master file", log_entries)
        sleep(0.25)



window.close()
```

This produces this error but even bypassing this, it doesn't work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 133, in add_to_log
    window[-'logtext-'].update(log_entries, text_color=text_colour)
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'
```

I can update the window after clicking a button but I don't know how to automatically create an event that triggers the update.

Thanks.

UPDATE: Thanks for your input. I fixed it by doing the update on the text element then refreshing the whole window. I thought one operation would do it all.

My function now looks like this:

```
        def add_to_log(window, text, log_entries, text_colour='black'):
            log_entries = log_entries + "\n" + text
            window['-logtext-'].update(log_entries, text_color=text_colour)
            window.refresh()
            return log_entries
```

The window looks like this: [image of log window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRPwZ.png)

One final question, does the interaction with the window all have to be in the `while True` loop? i.e. will I have to indent every line of code I've done for processes that follow the first display of the window?

By the way, I love PSG and all the resources. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: You can update at any point.  The important things it to periodically call `window.refresh()` so that your window doesn't appear to the user that it has frozen.  Changes will not be shown until you call `refresh` or `read`. All of the documentation and docstrings on the update methods tell you this https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#text-element

Comment: `-'logtext-'` get `TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'`

Comment:  gotta move that `'` over to the left.

Comment: Doesn't have to be in a while loop.  Post future questions on the PySimpleGUI github and it'll be easier to converse.